# Twitter-Bootstrap 3.3.1 - DataTables always horizontal scrollable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I've just updated from Bootstrap 3.2.0 to Bootstrap 3.3.1. I'm also using the [DataTables-Plugin](http://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap) and therefore, I'm using dataTables.bootstrap.css and dataTables.bootstrap.js, respectively.

With version 3.2.0 I didn't have any problems, so far. With version 3.3.1 all tables are slightly scrollable in the horizontal direction (see screenshot).

[image: screenshot]

I've got the table within a `<div class="table-responsive">` tag. So normally, the horizontal scrollbar should be displayed on smaller screens but not by default.

Any ideas?

Comment: use firebug in order to see which element has the css overflow: scroll

Comment: In version 3.3.1 I find `.table-responsive {min-height: .01%; overflow-x: auto;}`. Interestingly, this is not part of any @media-selector. When I remove the `overflow-x` it works. In version 3.2.0 I don't find the mentioned selector. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not really solve the problem, as the scrollbar will be missing when you resize your window. It reappears when a lower media query gets activated, though.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

In  Bootstrap v3.3.4 bootstrap.min.css .table-responsive {min-height: .01%; overflow-x: auto;}
is causing the problem
So instead of changing in bootstrap core css file (As it is not recommended)

I edit following lines of code in my custom css file to override bootstrap css

```
.table-responsive {
  overflow-x: inherit;
}
```

This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The tables produced by DataTables are configured to be responsive already. So you don't need to enclose them in a bootstrap "table-responsive" div.

Your code might look like this:

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table" id="myTable">
            .... blah blah ...
        </table>
    </div>
```

Then later in javascript you make it a responsive DataTables table:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({ responsive: true });
```

This is redundant and causes the extra scroll bar. Just remove the table-responsive div.

Comment: Datatable responsiveness is sheet. doing `responsive:true` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Any of the answers is working for me.

I could fix it adding a width="100% !important" to the table.

```
.table-responsive table{
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do need the table responsive class for mobile web responsive. So, what I do is creating a CSS class with @media only like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 968px) {
/* disable responsive in desktop */
.disable-in-desktop {
  overflow-x: inherit;
}
```

}

Then I call the .disable-in-desktop next to table-responsive, so it looks like:

```
            <div class="table-responsive disable-in-desktop">
```

- Conclusion:
  Now, the responsive class will only work on a mobile screen, because I disabled it on the desktop screen. So the horizontal scroll doesn't occur anymore.
  Sorry for the bad English language.

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to find a great answer for why this is occurring.  It looks like, for me at least, DataTables is creating the table 1-3 pixels wider than the container.  This is always yielding an active horizontal scroll bar.  I didn't want to disable the ability to have a responsive table at other resolutions or even lock it into certain sizes, so here's my solution:

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable({
    drawCallback: function(settings) {
        // fix to remove unnecessary width
        let $table = $(this);
        let diff = $table.parent().width() - $table.width();

        if (diff > 0 && diff < 3) {
            $table.width($table.width() - 4);
        }
    }
});
```

Now every time the table is resized, it will make sure the table is 4 pixels smaller than the container it is in, but only if it is within 3 pixels of the parent container.  This will still allow it to be responsive at smaller screen sizes, but resize the table a few pixels when it is barely oversized.

Answer (score -1):

put this in your custom.css, the datatable auto generate .row is affecting the scroll bar when is autoflow-x..

```
#example_wrapper .row{
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-left:-15px;  
}
```